# Can't launch app, "transparent" error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I try to launch android app on Xamarin, but have this error:

`string types not allowed (at 'background' with value 'transparent')`

What i can do? I have 'transparent' on ImageButton

Answer (score 2):

Replace `'transparent'` with `"#00000000"`
Using a raw RGB color value should work